# Postgres getting error on NOT NULL constraint when updating by a defined value (i.e. "something")

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to add columns and some of them are with the constraint `NOT NULL`. After I add columns I try to update values and there are no NULL values for those columns but I get error `ERROR: column "my_col1" contains null values`.
Here is my script:

```
alter table my_table
    ADD COLUMN "my_col1" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    ADD COLUMN "my_col2" varchar(256),
    ADD COLUMN "my_col3" varchar(64);
    
update my_table mt1
set "my_col1" = mt2.my_col1,
    "my_col2" = mt2.my_col2,
    "my_col3" = mt2.my_col3,
from (
    select id,
           my_json_col::jsonb->>'myCol1' as my_col1,
           my_json_col::jsonb->>'myCol2' as my_col2,
           my_json_col::jsonb->>'myCol3' as my_col3,
    from my_table mt
    ) mt2
where mt1.id = mt2.id
```

The table `my_table` has a jsonb column `my_json_col` with all those fields, and I want to add separate columns and fill with the values accordingly to remove jsonb column then.

This part:

```
select id,
    my_json_col::jsonb->>'myCol1' as my_col1,
    my_json_col::jsonb->>'myCol2' as my_col2,
    my_json_col::jsonb->>'myCol3' as my_col3,
from my_table mt
```

gives me the values without NULL for `my_col1`. Then why I get such error??

Comment: Why do you use double quotes around the column names? This is at least unnecessary and could even be the reason of such issues. Furthermore, where is the table or alias `dor2` defined? You want to use `dor2.my_col1`, but I don't see such a table in your code.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Sorry. I've edited the question (replaced dor2 with mt2)

Comment: @JonasMetzler I tried without double quotes also - the same result.

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle to make people here able to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in update query. You can not add columns with NOT NULL constraint without DEFAULT value.
In your case you need to add NULLable columns, fill them with data parsed from JSON field, after that you can apply NOT NULL constraint.

```
create table my_table (
    id serial,
    my_json_col jsonb
);

insert into my_table (my_json_col) values ('{"myCol1":"111","myCol2":"222","myCol3":"333"}'::jsonb);

alter table my_table
    ADD COLUMN "my_col1" varchar(32),
    ADD COLUMN "my_col2" varchar(256),
    ADD COLUMN "my_col3" varchar(64);
    
update my_table mt1
set "my_col1" = mt2.my_col1,
    "my_col2" = mt2.my_col2,
    "my_col3" = mt2.my_col3
from (
    select id,
           my_json_col::jsonb->>'myCol1' as my_col1,
           my_json_col::jsonb->>'myCol2' as my_col2,
           my_json_col::jsonb->>'myCol3' as my_col3
    from my_table mt
    ) mt2
where mt1.id = mt2.id;

alter table my_table alter column "my_col1" SET NOT NULL;

select * from my_table;
```

[Test the solution on SQLize](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql15/996604ef02c3ed14759a4e0d2374cfc8/)

Comment: @SlavaRozhev thanks. I figured that out by myself. But anyway I'll accept your answer as correct in order to help anyone with the same issue.